# Keep Material UI TextField label on top when text field has no value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So this should be simple but I don't see a clear answer.
The labels I have looks like this:

[image].

As you can see the bottom 2 fields have the label on top since they have a default value whereas the top on "ML Features" does not and the label moves to the middle of the `TextField`.

The code looks like this:

```
<TextField
    label="ML Features" // or any other field
    ...
   >
</TextField>
```

How can I keep the label always on the top?

Comment: Note that this is particularly important if you are setting the value for a disabled prop since then it overwrites the displayed value (at least in v5 as of posting).  Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 117, accepted):

You can set `shrink` to `true` in `InputLabelProps`. For more reference, see `InputLabel` API [here](https://mui.com/api/input-label/#:%7E:text=is%20required.-,shrink,-bool).

```js
<TextField label="ML Features" InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }} />
```

Comment: this seems to be the direction, and does do what you said. The issue is that for some reason when I do this all the text fields are now double the width!
I looked at the api and tried using `margin: "dense" ` but this did not reduce the size of the text fields

Comment: @Michael I need a minimum reproducible example. When you add `shrink: true`, the label is [translated](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/662b8bf5af0d6e31f009e688c5341570a13e4e83/packages/material-ui/src/InputLabel/InputLabel.js#L39-L42) to the top using [tag:css-transforms], it should not affect your `TextField` width in any way.

Comment: it's good for some reason behavior was strange with devtools open.

Answer (score 3):

you need to add focused

so that it will be in top without any value

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).