# How to properly align InputLabel in Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

[image]

This is my code and this is how the InputLabel is being placed.
How do I style it to make it look better.
Here is my code :

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel >Select EPE</InputLabel>
        <Select
            labelId="select-EPE"
            id="select-EPE"
            label="EPE"
            
            onChange={(event)=>{
                setEPE_Record_Name(event.target.value);
                EPE_Data.name = event.target.value
            }}
        >

        {response ? response.map((item)=>{
            return (<MenuItem value = {item.Name}>  {item.Name} </MenuItem>);
        } ) : null}
        
        </Select>
        
        </FormControl>
```

Also when I select an option it overlaps with the label.
[image]

The response part only checks and creates a dropdown option for every existing value in response array.

```
{response ? response.map((item)=>{
        return (<MenuItem value = {item.Name}>  {item.Name} </MenuItem>);
    } ) : null}
```

How do I fix the label properly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Material-UI - Outlined select label is not rendering properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67064682/material-ui-outlined-select-label-is-not-rendering-properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for anyone curious, I solved the issue by changing this one part of the code. Use Textfield instead of Select.

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
        
        <TextField 
        select 
        variant={"outlined"} 
        label="Select EPE"
        onChange={(event)=>{
            setEPE_Record_Name(event.target.value);
            EPE_Data.name = event.target.value
        }}
        >

        {response ? response.map((item)=>{
            return (<MenuItem value = {item.Name}>  {item.Name} </MenuItem>);
        } ) : null}
        
        </TextField>
        
        </FormControl>
```

Comment: Thank you that one worked for me 
and I had to add also
margin="normal"
so it renders in the correct position