# MUI Select variant="filled" vertically misaligned text

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

When using a MUI v5 (5.0.4) `Select` component with `variant='filled'`, the text of the selected item is incorrectly aligned vertically: it sits at the bottom, while the select arrow icon is correctly vertically centered.

[image: incorrectly rendered Select variant='filled' component]

```js
<Grid
  container
  direction="column"
  style={{ minWidth: "35em", maxWidth: "60em" }}
  >
  <Typography variant="subtitle1">Appearance</Typography>
  <Card>
    <List>
      <ListItem>
        <ListItemText primary="Theme" />
        <ListItemSecondaryAction>
          <Select variant="filled" value={0}>
            <MenuItem value={0}>user preference</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={1}>light</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={2}>dark</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </ListItemSecondaryAction>
      </ListItem>
    </List>
  </Card>
</Grid>
```

I want to use the "filled" variant, as it was the default for MUI v4 before. How to fix this?

[image: Edit settings-filled-select-issue]

For reference, this is my [codesandbox example for MUI v4](https://codesandbox.io/s/settings-filled-select-issue-muiv4-x31te), which worked as shown next (maybe by accident?):

[image: Select MUIv4 without label]

Comment: By design, the `filled` variant expect an `InputLabel` text. For that they are forcing the text little bit down. Either you can use `InputLabel` or fix the bottom.

Comment: the filled `Select` saves some space at the top for the label in case you supply it, you can play around with the example [here](https://mui.com/components/selects/#filled-and-standard-variants) and see that it works as expected. The question now is do you want the selected value always vertically aligned?

Comment: @NearHuscarl I've updated the codesandbox but I must be doing something wrong, as the `InputLabel` is rendered in the wrong place. Besides that, is this a breaking change from MUI v4, because I never used an `InputLabel` before in v4 and it worked perfectly with the default variant, which seems to be `filled` in v4?

Comment: @TheDiveO If you use label in a `Select`, the easiest way is to switch to `TextField` with the select mode instead. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67068903/9449426) answer for more detail.

Comment: I've wrapped all in a `FormControl`, so that the `InputLabel` now gets positioned correctly. But still, `Select` doesn't behave correctly when according to the documentation example you link to it should?

Comment: It works in my codesandbox from the answer I linked you if you change the variant to [filled](https://codesandbox.io/s/67064682-material-ui-outlined-select-label-is-not-rendering-properly-forked-53sgi?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: You're missing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65arV.png) label from my answer. That's why I recommend you to use `TextField` first as it prevents you from making these kind of errors.

Comment: You probably refer to `FormControl variant='filled'`? Anyway, where do I remove `Select`'s top padding to make it work as before in MUI v4? (I've added the `InputLabel`, but if I don't want it, how do I remove the padding?)

Comment: I'm a bit confused, the v4 filled `Select` looks the same to the one in v5. [See](https://v4.mui.com/components/selects/#simple-select) this section. Can you point me to the codesandbox where to v4 works for you?

Comment: Not a codesandbox, but the production code using MUI v4: https://github.com/TheDiveO/lxkns/blob/10f0f0b9c9efdbeafc2830f1a8707c0a734925ae/web/lxkns/src/views/settings/Settings.tsx#L87

Comment: the v4 one works because you use the default variant `standard`, in v5 you change it to `filled`, the reason why `filled` doesn't work I explained below. the reason `standard` works is because the label appears above of the input area, so the selected value doesn't need to move itself down. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neT9l.png).

Comment: @TheDiveO I think there is a misunderstanding here, according to the v4 docs, the default variant of the `Select` [is standard](https://v4.mui.com/api/select/), not filled. in v5, they changed it to outlined.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [filled](https://material.io/components/text-fields#filled-text-field) `TextField` in material design. When you use `TextField`/`Select` with filled variant, it's best to use with a label, the intention is that the label occupies the top half while the selected value occupied the other bottom half.

[image: a]

But if you don't want to put a label inside the filled area, you can set `hiddenLabel` to true so the `FilledInput` knows that there won't be a label and vertically align the selected value for you:

```
<TextField
  select
  variant="filled"
  value={0}
  hiddenLabel
>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: From reading the MUI `Select` component source code, I've found that `FormControl hiddenLabel` does the job as this is a settings page using more extensive setting descriptions anyway.

Comment: @TheDiveO you're right, I missed that one in front of me, looks like it the specific prop for [FilledInput](https://mui.com/api/filled-input/#main-content), the other variants don't have it.