# MUI Select | Change how the selected value display in Input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I have an array of objects and I want to bind multiple properties of object in `MenuItem` but I want to display only a single property to be displayed in `Select`

[image]

In Above image it is showing 10-xyz in select display, it should only show 10.

```
const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState([
    {
      name: "xyz",
      age: "10"
    },
    { name: "xyz", age: "20" }
  ]);
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Select
      labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
      id="demo-simple-select"
      value={age}
      label="Age"
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
      {options.map((ele) => {
        return(<MenuItem value={ele.age}>
          {`${ele.age}-${ele.name}`} 
        </MenuItem>)
      })}
    </Select>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `renderValue` prop to change how the `Select` should display the value in the `Input` component:

```
<Select renderValue={(p) => p}
```

There are 2 more problems in your code:

1. You should pass a `key` in your `MenuItem` to differentiate between each of them in the list. See [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) for more explanation.
2. You should use `TextField` instead of `Select` if you want to display a `label` for your `Select` as explained in my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67068903/9449426).

I've fixed both issues in the demo below.

For reference, see the `Select` API [here](https://mui.com/api/select/#:%7E:text=(default).-,renderValue,-func).

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 0):

You're concatenating both keys in the return:

Switch from:

```
{`${ele.age}-${ele.name}`}
```

To this:

```
{`${ele.age}`}
```