# MUI Select, top border doesn't show

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Could anyone please say what can be the reason for such behaviour of select field? I am a new developer on the project, and assume that someone has somehow changed it.
[image]

```
          <mui.FormControl style={{ width: '598px' }}>
            <mui.InputLabel id="label">{t('profile.student.transcriptScreen.selectCourse')}</mui.InputLabel>
            <mui.Select labelId="label" value={values.category ?? ''} name="category" onChange={handleChange}>
              <mui.MenuItem value={'MATH'}>Math</mui.MenuItem>
              <mui.MenuItem value={'ENGLISH'}>English</mui.MenuItem>
              <mui.MenuItem value={'SCIENCE'}>Science</mui.MenuItem>
              <mui.MenuItem value={'SOCIAL'}>Social Studies</mui.MenuItem>
              <mui.MenuItem value={'ELECTIVES'}>Electives</mui.MenuItem>
            </mui.Select>
          </mui.FormControl>
```

Comment: There could be many things obscuring it, your best shot is dev tools and trying to see what is going on in the HTML & CSS around that input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                <mui.InputLabel id="course-name-label">
                  {t('common:subjectCourseName', {
                    subject:
                      values.category === 'SOCIAL_STUDIES'
                        ? 'Social Studies'
                        : values.category.toLowerCase().charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
                          values.category.toLowerCase().slice(1),
                  })}
                </mui.InputLabel>
                <mui.OutlinedInput
                  name="name"
                  value={values.name ?? ''}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  label={t('common:subjectCourseName', {
                    subject:
                      values.category === 'SOCIAL_STUDIES'
                        ? 'Social Studies'
                        : values.category.toLowerCase().charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
                          values.category.toLowerCase().slice(1),
                  })}
                ></mui.OutlinedInput>
              </mui.FormControl>
```

```
export const categoryOptions = [
  { id: 'MATH', name: 'Math' },
  { id: 'ENGLISH', name: 'English' },
  { id: 'SCIENCE', name: 'Science' },
  { id: 'SOCIAL_STUDIES', name: 'Social Studies' },
  { id: 'ELECTIVES', name: 'Electives' },
];
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably missing the `label` parameter to `mui.Select`. I also suggest you change `id="label"` and `labelId="label"` to something specific. It will help you and any other developer clarify what it is identifying, something like `course-selection-label`.

Try adding the `label` property:

```
<mui.FormControl style={{ width: '598px' }}>
            <mui.InputLabel id="course-selection-label">{t('profile.student.transcriptScreen.selectCourse')}</mui.InputLabel>
            <mui.Select labelId="course-selection-label" value={values.category ?? ''} name="category" onChange={handleChange} label="Course">
              <mui.MenuItem value={'MATH'}>Math</mui.MenuItem>
              <mui.MenuItem value={'ENGLISH'}>English</mui.MenuItem>
              <mui.MenuItem value={'SCIENCE'}>Science</mui.MenuItem>
              <mui.MenuItem value={'SOCIAL'}>Social Studies</mui.MenuItem>
              <mui.MenuItem value={'ELECTIVES'}>Electives</mui.MenuItem>
            </mui.Select>
          </mui.FormControl>
```

Sources:

[MUI's Select Component](https://mui.com/components/selects/#labels-and-helper-text) as well as
[This specific SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67068903/5467710)

Comment: I was trying this option before posting it here, but used 'label' as id, and specified label property. By changing the label id it now displays normal. Thank you!